# rails query by count on has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, for example, Post, and a Post `has_many` comments. I would like to query posts in order of posts with the most comments to the least. How can I do this with an active record query?

Right now I am trying:

```
Post.includes(:comments).order('COUNT(comments.post_id) DESC')
```

but I am getting the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "comments")
```

Comment: What database are you using? This matters in this case for grouping reasons

Comment: postgres. I just updated my question with some example code as well.

Comment: `Post.includes(:comments).references(:comments).group(:id).order('COUNT(comments.post_id) DESC')` should do it. `includes` will not automatically join the table in your case but `references` will tell it to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:comments)
    .group(:id) # required by Postgres
    .order(Arel.sql('COUNT(comments.*) DESC')) # https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32995
```

If you want to use the count in the result you can select it as well:

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:comments)
    .select('posts.*, COUNT(comments.*) AS comment_count')
    .group(:id) # required by Postgres
    .order('comment_count DESC') # Use COUNT(comments.*) in Oracle
```

Another way to solve this is by using [counter_cache](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache).

Comment: `left_outer_joins` was introduced in Rails 5. Use `.includes` if you need backwards compatibility.

Comment: ^the hero we need, but not the one we deserve

Comment: Well if we are going to `arel` then let's do it all the way. `Comment.arel_table[:id].count.desc` = `COUNT(comments.id) DESC`

Comment: @engineersmnky `Arel.sql('COUNT(comments.*) DESC')` is really just a way to mark the SQL string as "trusted". This is due to the changes in Rails 6  to prevent idiots from getting SQL injections by doing `.order(params[:order])`.

Comment: I am certainly aware of what it is but my suggestion keeps you from having to use a `String` at all an ensures sanitary output, which is why I mentioned it. It also lends to refactoring maintainability if the `Comment` class were to change since we are referencing the class rather than explicitly the table name in string form.

Comment: Except that `COUNT *` is ever so slightly faster than `COUNT pk`. I guess you could do `Comment.arel_table[:*].count.desc`.

Comment: Actually its `Comment.arel_table[Arel.star].count.desc`.